# How to remove # in front of a line with sed?

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to uncomment (removing #) the line `sql`.

```
session {
        radutmp

        #
        #  See "Simultaneous Use Checking Queries" in sql.conf
#       sql
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/#       sql/        sql/' /etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel
```

But somehow the spaces are not correctly calculated. It doesn't find `#       sql`.

Comment: Are you sure it's spaces and not a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376426/how-to-remove-in-front-of-a-line-with-sed/47376460#comment81705209_47376426) it looks like the input file is using tabs instead of spaces. You can use the `[:blank:]` character class which includes both tabs and spaces:

```
sed '/#[[:blank:]]*sql/s/#//' file
```

The command matches lines with the sequence `#`, zero or more spaces followed by the term `sql` and removes the first `#`

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is enough to match space or tabs. `[[:space:]]` will match space, tab, newline, carriage return, form-feed and vertical tab.

Comment: I've changed it to `[:blank:]`

Answer (score 0):

Using sed `-E` option:

```
> sed -E 's/#(\s+sql)/\1/i' /etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel
                      ^ holds matching chunk from within first capturing group
```

`\s` means a character class which denotes `[\t\n\r\f\v ]` characters. `\s+` ensures that there should be some kind of spaces following `#`